# Can't pip install pystan

Tags: python, installation, pip, pystan

I am **not** able to `pip install fbprophet` neither to `pip install pystan`.

I am using VS Code and Python 3.9.3 64-bit on Windows 10. I also updated to the newest version of Visual Studio Build tools (16.11.3) since some people are saying, you need at least Visual Studio C++ 14.0 for using `pystan`.

```
Collecting pystan
  Using cached pystan-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting clikit<0.7,>=0.6
  Using cached clikit-0.6.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<4.0,>=3.6
  Using cached aiohttp-3.7.4.post0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (634 kB)
Collecting pysimdjson<4.0,>=3.2
  Using cached pysimdjson-3.2.0-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (157 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement httpstan<4.6,>=4.5 (from pystan) (from versions: 0.2.5, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.4.0, 0.5.0, 0.6.0, 0.7.2, 0.7.3, 0.7.5, 0.7.6, 0.8.0, 0.9.0, 0.10.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for httpstan<4.6,>=4.5 (from pystan)
```

Also trying to install httpstan doesnt work and also gives me even more errors.
I have seen people using conda/anaconda, but I dont use that.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: A workaround for the problem mentioned in DeepSpace's answer may be to use CmdStanPy. It's at least a Python interface that will work with an up-to-date version of Stan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in installing `httpstan`. You are using Windows, but according to its [`pypi` page](https://pypi.org/project/httpstan/) it only supports Linux and MacOS. This is confirmed by the [list of wheels](https://pypi.org/project/httpstan/#files).

You may bypass this by using a VM or docker, both of which are out-of-scope of this question so try to research that.